# How to apply drag and drop in iframe from outside HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, drag-and-drop

Assume that I have following HTML file:

**
main.html
**

```
<html>
<body>
<ul>
<li>Element to drag</li>
</ul>

<iframe src="demo.html">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**demo.html** (iframe code)

```
<body class="iframe">

</body>
```

I'm using jquery UI for drag and drop ([Link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/))
And assume that all javascript files are included in main.html and demo.html

Any help would be great helpful !!!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and manage to do it this way.

Consider the draggable element in your main file normally and refer to the iframe droppable elements with

```
$( 'your-iframe' ).contents().find( 'elments-you-want-droppable' ).droppable({

    // droppable settings here as normal

});
```